# PySide2 Qt clashes with other Qt in the system?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm getting following error while running the following code.

**Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c05) with this library (version 0x50d02)**

How to debug this?

```
import sys
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "Hei maailma", "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)


    def magic(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your code but it seems that you have Qt installed whose version is different from the one you installed with PySide2.

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with pyqt

Comment: I also thought so but I'm not able to decide what should be the best way to debug this. should I downgrade Qt from PySide2 or I should upgrade pyQt?

Comment: Recommendation: uninstall both. And create a virtualenv for each library so you avoid problems.

Comment: On the other hand, both bindings currently use the same version of Qt, Qt 5.13.2, which should not cause you problems.

Comment: I did create a venv, interstingly i find following, **print (PySide2.QtCore.__version__) = 5.13.2** but from PyQt5 import QtCore **print(QtCore.PYQT_VERSION)=330755** and on the other hand qdiag output shows **Qt 5.12.5 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 7.3.0) on "xcb"**

Comment: I have recommended you create 2 virtualenvs: one for PyQt5 and one for PySide2

Comment: why PySide2.QtCore and QtCore for pyQt5 do not show same version in the freshly installed environment

Comment: On the other hand update PyQt5 since the latest version is PyQt5 5.13.2 that uses Qt 5.13.2

Comment: Because you haven't installed the latest version of both.

Comment: **pip freeze | grep -i "^PyQt"
PyQt5==5.13.2
PyQt5-sip==12.7.0
PyQtWebEngine==5.12.1**
(pyQt) wasim@DNA:/opt/Anaconda3/envs$ **pip freeze | grep -i "^PySide"
PySide2==5.13.2** still getting that error and still qdiag output shows **Qt 5.12.5 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 7.3.0) on "xcb"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202219/discussion-between-wasim-aftab-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: So it's probably a conda bug, report it.

Comment: I filed a conda bug https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9432, but still wondering if qtdiag output has some clue towards fixing this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using  qt 5.12.5 from conda-forge and pyqt from pip wheels (https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/issues/921#issuecomment-553094850).

Finally, I got rid of that annoying bug as follows:

1. by making sure I have **same versions of PyQt5 and PySide2** installed
2. by removing qt from my environment: **conda remove -n myEnv qt**